# String index for a list of values using IN($1,$2): will a btree index work?

Tags: postgresql, index, string

We have a query that needs to compare a value to a list of values in a where clause. The strings are known and discrete. Does IN use the `=` operator to compare values? Would a b-tree index work for this use case? Example query:

```
 create table fruit (
   name character varying NOT null
 )

 select * from fruit where name in ('Banana', 'Apple');
```

Let's assume at the moment we do not want to normalize the data (even though I agree that makes the most sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `IN` statement can be considered a chained `OR`, e.g. `WHERE name IN ('Banana','Apple')` is equivalent to `WHERE (name = 'Banana' OR name = 'Apple')`.

The data is normalized once you define `Name` as your primary key as that would uniquely identify a fruit for the purposes of this example.  So if that was your primary key, there would be a B-tree present and the engine would (generally) do two seeks for your query: one for 'Banana' and one for 'Apple'.

If there was a secondary index on `Name`, the engine would (again, generally) do two seeks on that index and two seeks against the table.

Comment: thanks, that makes a lot of sense!